# Is there a USB Scale that works like a keyboard (like a barcode scanner)?

Tags: javascript, pos

I'm developing a web app with JavaScript to manage inventory. I've already implemented a barcode scanner and it works as if it were a simple keyboard. When it scans something, it just "types" the code.

Is there a USB Scale that works like that? The scales I found work with drivers and serial communication for low and middle-level programming languages.

Comment: This is not likely as for a scale, you would need a _trigger_ to know when to capture and send the data, else it would continually stream. Also this is off topic and I am voting to close.

Comment: This isn't the place for this question. Check out the list of other stacks.